# java println running function not returning function

Tags: java, return, println

[**FULL GITHUB FILES FOUND HERE**](https://github.com/Blackflames64/Casino)

This is class `Roulette.java`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  System.out.println("Welcome to roulette " + Casino.player());
}
```

This is class `Casino.java`

```
public static String player() {
   Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

   String name;
   System.out.println("Please enter your name : ");
   name = sc.nextLine();

   return name;
}
```

When running `Roulette.java` it's not printing `Casino.player()` as a variable of your name, but running the function and asking for your name. I want to run `Casino.java` first,ask your name, then run roulette and welcome you with your name. NOT ASK YOUR NAME AGAIN.

Note: New to programming

Comment: I'm not entirely clear what you're asking.  Is the code not working as you expect?  If not, what is it doing, and why is it different from what you're expecting?

Comment: When I run `Roulette.java` it's asking for my name, I don't want it to do that, I want it to ask my name only in `Casino.java` and save the name there and use it in other class with `Casino.player()`.

Comment: Why do you have `main` methods in each of your files? There should be a single point of entry for your project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `player()` method in the `Casino` class prints out the message to input the users name. This will happen every time the method is called. To do what you want to do you need to create a conditional that checks if the player has already been set.

NOTE: This is not good practice or class design and in the future you should look into proper practice for class design and setting fields in a class. I would suggest posting this code on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) once you get it working to get a full answer on how this design can be improved.

Your `Casino` class should look something like this:

```
public class Casino {
    private static String player = "";

    public static String player() {
        if (player.equals("")) {
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Please enter your name : ");
            this.player = sc.nextLine();;
        }
        return player;
    }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't `player` be a static variable, since it is being referenced in a static method?

Comment: Your `player` variable will need to be static if used from a static method.  Other than that, I'd do the same thing.

Comment: This worked! Thank you so much for teaching me. Note: It needed to be static,

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
String player = Casino.player();

System.out.println("Welcome to roulette " + player);
```

Comment: Nope, still does the same thing.

Comment: @MichaelMansour I made a mistake in my initial comment and quickly corrected it, perhaps you didn't see the correction?

Comment: I used your updated code and it does the same thing, perhaps look at the 2 files Roulette.java and Casino.java in github.